# Flutter is not recognized

Tags: visual-studio, flutter

I have been trying to figure this out for awhile, and Ive followed all of the steps that have been outlined in older posts. I cannot seem to get this to work - regardless of how many times I edit the environmental variables. I have pasted the error message I keep getting from visual source code, but I have also attempted to troubleshoot in CMD.

flutter : The term 'flutter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- flutter doctor
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (flutter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

I have modified the environmental variables, and have attached a picture:

System Environmental Variables:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try typing this in your console:

```
C:\src\flutter> .\flutter_console
```

This should help it run smoothly if your environment variables are set properly.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is arising due to you have put flutter folder inside an elevated user folder.

- Extract the zip file and place the contained flutter in the desired installation location for the Flutter SDK (for example, `C:\src\flutter`).
- Warning: Do not install Flutter in a directory like `C:\Program Files\` that requires elevated privileges.

Your Environment path variable will look like this:

[image: Environment Path Variable].

Answer (score 0):

First, run `flutter doctor` in Git Bash to see if you installed flutter.

If you get an error there, then you haven't installed flutter correctly, but if you don't get an error move the Flutter SDK folder to a location like `C:\src\flutter` and then add it to your path. It will work.